# Pygame : Keyboard event not detected (Following Catalina Update Mac)

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard, keyboard-events, macos-catalina

I am trying to run the code below using python and pygame and I tried many things but i could find the solution for the program to detect the keyboard (arrows) events... And I am beginning to think that it is linked to the Catalina update of my Mac OS. Before the update, this code was working alright... I guess it has to do with the "Accessibility" between Python/Terminal and the rights I give to these 2 applications but I can't find the exact "right access" that solves the problem...

Anyone has an idea ? :)

```
# coding=utf-8

# imports the Pygame library
import pygame


def main():
    # initializes Pygame
    pygame.init()

    # sets the window title
    pygame.display.set_caption(u'Keyboard events')

    # sets the window size
    pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

    # infinite loop
    while True:
        # gets a single event from the event queue
#        event = pygame.event.wait()
        pygame.event.pump()

        # if the 'close' button of the window is pressed
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # stops the application
            break

        # captures the 'KEYDOWN' and 'KEYUP' events
        if event.type in (pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP):
            # gets the key name
            key_name = pygame.key.name(event.key)

            # converts to uppercase the key name
            key_name = key_name.upper()

            # if any key is pressed
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # prints on the console the key pressed
                print("{} key pressed".format(key_name))

            # if any key is released
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # prints on the console the released key
                print("{} key released".format(key_name))

    # finalizes Pygame
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You've never defined `event` so this program will crash with `NameError`. Are you sure this is the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process keyboard events, use a for loop. For example:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        break

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print(f"{event.key} key pressed")
```

I'm not sure how your code worked before.